# Vue cannot use the <script import>?

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs3, vite

I was making a website in VueJS but it isn't working. App.vue at the top has

```
<script setup>
  import Page from './components/Page.vue';
  import Top from './components/Top.vue';
</script>
```

When I try to run dev mode: **vite dev (npm run dev)** or try to build it: **vite (npm run build)** it dosent like the last **>** at `</script>`

Note: I'm using **JS** instead of **TS**

It will **not** compile or even run the dev server.

**ERROR:**

```
Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
11:07:43 am [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/src/App.vue
  1  |  <script setup>
  2  |    import Page from '.Page.vue';
  3  |    import Top from '.Top.vue';
  4  |  </script>
     |           ^
  5  |
  6  |
      at formatError (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:40862:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:40858:19)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:37530:22)
      at async Object.transform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:41111:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:37373:29)
Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
11:08:30 am [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.     
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/src/App.vue
  1  |  <script setup>
  2  |    import Top from './components/Top.vue';
  3  |    import Page from './components/Page.vue';
  4  |  </script>
     |           ^
  5  |
  6  |
      at formatError (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:40862:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:40858:19)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:37530:22)
      at async Object.transform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:41111:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///D:/Developing/denhamrocknet/home/denhamrockjs/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-49b3b5ea.js:37373:29)
```

**END**

I have no idea why. Ive found out that setting: `module.exports = { publicPath: '' }` otherwise it is just a blank page although when I do I get this error **and** a white page.

***PS: Anything helps! Ill try anything. I'm desperate for it to work.***

---

**Fixed Issue!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I FOUND A FIX!**

I just removed: `module.exports = { publicPath: '' }` from my config and now it works! I must have made an error, added the code, fixed the error, and now removed the bad code.

**Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue!**